# Runtime error '3075' in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I know there are plenty of posts with the same title, but I couldn't find anything similar to my problem.

I'm trying to update a record with SQL in VBA. In particular, my code goes to an excel file, extracts a value, asks the user for the ID of the record that needs to be updated, and then should procced to do the update. The thing is i tried running the same code without the user input, and works just fine, so the problem must be with the interpretation of the input. I checked that everything is a string but i don't know how to solve the problem.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Dim query2 as string
Dim myID as string
myID = InputBox("Insert ID:")
query2 = "UPDATE [Info test] " & "SET RESULT = " & var & "WHERE ID =" & myID
DoCmd.RunSQL (query2)
```

In this case, var is a string, and is the value i fetch from the excel file.
From various tests, i think the problem is with the last & myID, like there is an apostrophe before the value stored by myID, but i don't know what to do about it, or if this is really the problem.

Thanks to everybody who can help

Comment: In the database is `Result` a text field and `ID` a numeric field?  When debugging what is the value of `var` & `myID`?  You say _like there is an apostrophe_ - is there?  You can place a break-point on that line of code so it pauses there and you can check the values.

Comment: can you add watch and paste query here?

Comment: Hit Ctrl+G to see the output of `Debug.Print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `Debug.Print query2` before DoCmd, run the code and check output in immediate window. This SQl should work in query builder. I believe you need to enclose var in single quotes and add a space before `WHERE`

```
query2 = "UPDATE [Info test] SET RESULT = '" & Replace(var, "'", "''") & "' WHERE ID =" & myID
```

I added Replace in order to avoid errors if `var` contains single quote.

Comment: Just to add to this answer: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570) @SabrinaMordini

Comment: Thank you, I needed to put the single quotes around myID, but when i tried this, I forgot an &. Now it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If var is a string, then you need to use single quotes and add space before WHERE like shown below

```
query2 = "UPDATE [Info test] " & "SET RESULT = '" & var & "' WHERE ID =" & myID
```